# Loop-correction for non-commutative quartic theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, non-commutative-theory

[image]

What is the meaning of the second, third and fourth graph? The image is from [arXiv:hep-th/9912072](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912072).

Answer (score 2):

1. The Feynman rules in [non-commutative field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_quantum_field_theory) are classified using ['t Hooft double-line notation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%27t+Hooft+double+line+notation). In particular, the legs in a vertex has a cyclic order, cf. eq. (2.5) in Ref. 1.
2. Interestingly, non-planar graphs are suppressed due to extra phase factors. (This is somewhat similar to the [planar limit/large-$N_c$-expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/N_expansion) in $SU(N_c)$ Yang-Mills theory, although the non-planar suppression is there caused because non-planar diagrams have fewer traces.)
3. Returning to OP's question, the second, third and fourth graph in Fig. 7 are non-planar graphs (again due to that the cyclic order of legs in vertices matters).

References:

1. S. Minwalla, M. Van Raamsdonk & N. Seiberg, *Non-commutative Perturbative Dynamics,* [arXiv:hep-th/9912072](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912072).

Comment: But how would I write down the four-point function for the non-planar diagrams?

Comment: The brief answer is: By applying the pertinent Feynman rules.